# Создание динамических элементов и работа с ними

Tags: jquery, javascript

На странице имеем:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://site.ru/wgt.js"></script>
<script>jQuery(document).ready(function(){wgt({param: value})});</script>
```

Нужно создавать эти элементы динамически (кроме подключения jquery). Делаю так:

```
(function (d, w) {
var n = d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0],
    s = d.createElement("script"),
    f = function () { n.parentNode.insertBefore(s, n); };
s.type = "text/javascript";
s.defer = true;
s.src = (d.location.protocol == "https:" ? "https:" : "http:") + "//site.ru/wgt.js";

if (w.opera == "[object Opera]") {
    d.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", f, false);
} else { f(); }
})(document, window);

var scriptContents = 'jQuery(document).ready(function(){wgt({param: value})})';
var theScript = document.createElement('script');
theScript.type = 'text/javascript';
theScript.defer = true;
theScript.appendChild(document.createTextNode(scriptContents));
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(theScript);
```

В консоли получаю ошибку, что

> Uncaught ReferenceError: wgt is not
> defined.

Как с этим бороться?

Comment: Посмотрите [книгу](http://yandex.ru/yandsearch?text=stoyan stefanov javascript  pdf) Стояна Стефанова «JavaScript Шаблоны» – в Главе 8 подробно рассматриваются **стратегии загрузки**.

Comment: Посмотрел, спасибо ... навело на мысли.  
Избавился от вызова jquery, создал iframe динамически и повесил вызов функции на событие onload как атрибута фрейма .. все работает.